# mvn release plugin releasing next snapshot not current release

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

Hello I've been releasing a project from my workstation with no problems.  I've recently tried releasing another project from 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.  However when it actually does the release it releases 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT to the snapshots repository instead of 1.0.0 to releases repository.
I've done dryRun=true and it seems fine.  In fact it defaults me to the versions:

```
What is the release version for "Appname"? (...) 1.0.0: :
What is SCM release tag or label for "Appname"? (...) Appname-1.0.0: :
What is the new development version for "Appname"? (...) 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT: :
```

I take all the defaults.
However when i do the "mvn release:perform" 
This is what it does:

```
[INFO] Uploading: http://{corporate-nexus-site}/snapshots/{app-path}/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/fei-logging-formatter-1.0.1-20140929.153303-1.jar
...
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

I'm using latest maven and i manually added latest release plugin.  And I can release another project using same parent and settings.xml setup.
Looking at the properties file after a dryrun and prepare it all looks right to me.
I thought originally i had my distribution set up wrong, and was releasing a release to the snapshot repository, but as you can see its actually thinking its doing a good job and releasing a snapshot.

confused royally.

Any ideas on what to try?

thanks.

**UPDATE**: In the project I updated the pom from 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.0 and did a "mvn deploy" and it put it exactly where I expected in releases, without out all the goodies of course.

**UPDATE2**: Pom (company name to protect the guilty)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>logging-formatter</groupId>
    <artifactId>logging-formatter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Logging Formatter</name>
    <description>logging tool to format your logging in the standard cn way.</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.companyname.pom.parent.master</groupId>
        <artifactId>cn-pom-parent-master</artifactId>
        <version>2014.3.0</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    </build>
    <scm>
        <url>http://svn.sys.ds.companyname.com/svn/cn-logging</url>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.sys.ds.companyname.com/svn/cn-logging</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn.sys.ds.companyname.com/svn/cn-logging</developerConnection>
    </scm>
    <organization>
        <name>CompanyName Enterprises</name>
    </organization>
    <ciManagement>
        <system>Jenkins</system>
        <url>http://jenkins.sys.ds.companyname.com:8080/job/cn-logging-DEVELOP/</url>
    </ciManagement>
</project>
```

UPDATE3: Adding parent settings info

```
      SETTINGS.XML
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>fei-releases</id>
          <name>Ferguson Release Repository</name>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <url>http://{companyname}/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>fei-snapshots</id>
          <name>Ferguson Snapshot Repository</name>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <url>http://{companyname}/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>fei-thirdparty</id>
          <name>Ferguson 3rd Party Repository</name>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <url>http://{companyname}/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
      </repositories>

      PARENT REPOSITORIES:
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>third-party</id>
        <name>3rd Party Repository</name>
        <url>http://{companyname}/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories/>

    PARENT DISTRIBUTION MANAGEMENT:
    <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>fei-releases</id>
      <name>Ferguson Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://{companyname}/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>fei-snapshots</id>
      <name>Ferguson Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>http://{companyname}/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

Comment: what is your SCM ? and what version of mvn-release-plugin are you using?

Comment: svn, and that works fine.  mvn-release = 2.5.1

Comment: did you try to "downgrade" to version 2.5, to see if it reproducible?

Comment: Can you describe the steps you have used to create the release in detail?

Comment: @QhadR I used the default version meaning I didn't declare any version explicitly, so an earlier version and had the same result as when I declared 2.5.1.

Comment: @khmarbaise i did a "mvn release:clean release:prepare" then a "mvn release:perform"  Same steps I used to release another project without issue using the same parent.

Comment: so you say that another project is working fine, meaning you release it and you see the expected version in repository, but in a specific project you see the "snapshot" version in the repo?

Comment: release:perform will "just" checkout the needed tag and perform a deploy, I would guess that the tagged POMs contain the SNAPSHOT version, which can be caused by a wrong SCM tag configuration in your POM.

Comment: @SteveHolt,
Please zoom in on the <scm> section of pom.xml file. I see a potential red flag in that none of the paths contain the 'trunk', 'branches' or 'tags' keywords.

What does <scm> contain for the SVN revision of the tag? What does <scm> contain for other projects that don't have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> i did a "mvn release:clean release:prepare" then a "mvn
>   release:perform" Same steps I used to release another project without
>   issue using the same parent.

So you have another project that is deployed fine after release? (you see the release version in the repo)?

If so, it sounds like an issue in your 'problematic' project. Can you share its pom.xml?

Comment: thats correct, everything worked as expected for another project(s).  Thats why this is so confusing.  I will share my project pom.  thanks

Comment: i see the pom. what is your repository? are you deploying to your local repo, or you have company-repo (Nexus/Artifactory/etc)? can you please also share your 'repository' section in your parent pom, or in the settings.xml?

Comment: yes using nexus at my company, i will post the relevant info.  thank you.

Comment: just to make sure: the settings.xml is common to the 2nd project that is working properly? and the parent pom as well? if so, the only diff between projects is the main pom.xml. is that correct?

Comment: that is correct, i did it on the same machine and did nothing to have it use a different settings file.  They are using the same parent.  Previous project worked as expected.  this one deploys to snapshots on release but creates a proper tag in svn.  on deploy it puts it releases repository as expected.  I know its sounds wack and I'm assuming i'm doing something wrong or have a faulty setup.  but i can't think of anything else.  I'm going to try a 3rd project this week and see what happens.

Comment: "on deploy it puts it releases repository as expected" - ??

Comment: if i change the pom from -SNAPSHOT to a release number manually and do a "mvn deploy" it automatically distributes it to /releases.

Comment: did you try the 3rd project?

Answer (score 0):

@SteveHolt,

I see a red flag in your pom.xml file:

```
<scm>
    <url>http://svn.sys.ds.companyname.com/svn/cn-logging</url>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.sys.ds.companyname.com/svn/cn-logging</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn.sys.ds.companyname.com/svn/cn-logging</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

None of these urls contain the `trunk`, `branches`, or `tags` keywords.

Consequently, when Maven creates the release tag, it tells SVN to use the same url as before:

```
http://svn.sys.ds.companyname.com/svn/cn-logging
```

When `release-prepare` runs, it performs

```
$ svn checkout http://svn.sys.ds.companyname.com/svn/cn-logging/
```

but it can't tell apart the release tag from the development trunk.

Therefore it retrieves the post-release snapshot revision (which is the latest commit) rather than the release revision (the preceding commit).

***Solution***:

Create a `trunk` dir under `cn-logging` and move all your code into it:

```
svn/cn-logging/
    trunk/
        pom.xml
        src/
            main/
            java/
    branches/
    tags/
```

Hope that helps.